# Check the value in textbox is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

Can anyone let me know how to check the value is selected in the html textbox using jquery. For example the value in the textbox if selected the text is slected with blue background.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? Its a bit unclear at the moment. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @zerkms he is after textbox though not checkbox, unless I am reading this wrong.

Comment: @Zerkms, he is asking for selected text inside a textbox. (I guess)

Comment: Hm... Why does the background's color matter anyway? :-"

Comment: @GazWinter : I mean the textbox. the color is just to make understand its not a select or a radio button. Got commond to select commond like window.selected() for outside the textbox but I am looking something which can get the selected value in the textbox. Please Help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/rT5vR/

```
var t = '';
if(window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
} else if(document.getSelection) {
    t = document.getSelection();
} else if(document.selection) {
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return t;
}

$("#myElement").select(function(eventObject) {
alert(getSelected().toString());
});
```

​Or

```
$('#myElement').select(function(e) {
var start = e.target.selectionStart;
var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
alert($('#myElement').val().substring(start, end));
});
```

​

The second one is perfect. Don't know how much cross-browser the first one is...
​

Comment: this code returns blank. Does not return any value.

Comment: Cool the second function returns something :) Thanks @A.V.

Comment: Happy to be Helpful...:)